# How to fix type issue for conditional rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to implement simple conditional rendering where if prefixText prop has more than 0 string then render double span elements else render single span element. But on prefixText.length I get error message saying ", is expected". Also on Text, I get "missing properties for ReactElement<any, any>" type error. How can I fix this issue?
https://codesandbox.io/s/text-component-v2dbt?file=/src/App.tsx:0-538

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface TextProps {
  children: string;
  prefixText?: string;
}

export const Text: React.FunctionComponent<TextProps> = ({
  children,
  prefixText
}: TextProps) => {

  return (
  { prefixText.length > 0 ?
    <span>
      <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{prefixText} </span>
      <span>{children}</span>
    </span> :
    <span>{children}</span>
  }
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Text prefixText="Tips:">favourite vacation</Text>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Beyond the given answers, you should care to default your `prefixText` to something because when undefined, accessing it via `length` should throw an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your return block code to as follows:

```
return (
  prefixText ?
    <span>
      <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{prefixText}</span>
      <span>{children}</span>
    </span> :
    <span>{children}</span>
);
```

Or update your component to the following:

```
export const Text: React.FunctionComponent<TextProps> = ({
  children,
  prefixText
}: TextProps) => (
  prefixText ?
    <span>
      <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{prefixText} </span>
      <span>{children}</span>
    </span> :
    <span>{children}</span>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your return statement into `React.Fragment`.

It should look like this

```
return (
  <>  
    { prefixText.length > 0 ? (
    
      <span>
        <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{prefixText} </span>
        <span>{children}</span>
      </span> 
    ) : (
      <span>{children}</span>
    )
  </>  
}
);
```

Or you can also get rid of return braces and create a construction like this:

```
return prefixText.length > 0 ? (
        <span>
          <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{prefixText} </span>
          <span>{children}</span>
        </span>
      ) : (
        <span>{children}</span>
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap your component with `react.fragment` and also check if `prefixText` exist in your condition
because `prefixText` is a partial in your typescript interface

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
      { prefixText && prefixText.length > 0 ?
      <span>
        <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{prefixText} </span>
        <span>{children}</span>
      </span> :
      <span>{children}</span>
    }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```